# How to install node js on gocd agent?

Tags: node.js, go-cd

While running node js app on gocd build pipeline i am get make sure npm install can be run on this agent.

How to install node js on gocd server to run test.

Answer (score 1):

> make sure npm install can be run on this agent. & 
>   How to install node js on gocd server to run test."

Both are completely two different things. You might have to spend little more time on understanding differences in responsibilities of GoCD server and Agent.

On a brief note you do not need to install nodejs on gocd server to run tests. All the tasks are run by "GoCD Agents". So you can go and manually install nodejs on GoCD agent (or) you can use nodejs docker container as agent which will have nodejs by default.